# How to define binary operation on arbitrary set in order to create a group structure.

Tags: group-theory

Is it (and if yes how?) possible to define an an binary operation $*$ for an arbitrary set $M$ such that $(M,*)$ is a group?

If $M$ is finite or countable infinite this is trivial, but is it also possible for any other sets? And if yes how can you construct $*$? If no can you provide a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is uncountable, the free group $F_M$ on $M$ has the same cardinality as $M$. Then with any bijection between $M$ and $F_M$ you get a group structure on $M$.

Comment: How can you show that $F_M$ and $M$ has the same cardinality? This does not seem obvious for me.

Comment: Let $X=M\cup M^{-1}\cup \{1\}$. An element of $F_M$ can be seen as an element of $X^\mathbb{N}$: $x_1\ldots x_n\in F_X$ can be seen as $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,1,1,\ldots)\in X^\mathbb{N}$. Can you see why $|X|=|X^\mathbb{N}|$? (this is not true if $X$ is countable). Now $|X|\leq |F_X|\leq |X^\mathbb{N}|$.

Answer (score 2):

By Löwenheim–Skolem theorem there are groups of arbitrary non-countable cardinality (because it's a first order theory). Therefore there exists a model G of cardinality exactly equals of M. Now it's trivial to copy the group structure of G to M.